# illegal unit of measure in tex code created from dot2tex

Tags: pstricks, coordinates, dot2tex

I am using `dot2tex` to convert some code from `graphviz` into LaTeX (PSTricks) drawings. However, I get following error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
l.21 ...newidth=1bp](0bp,0bp)(1.2057e+05bp,1028bp)
```

Attached is the mwe.

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{100cm}
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1bp](0bp,0bp)(1.2057e+05bp,1028bp)
  \pstVerb{2 setlinejoin} % set line join style to 'mitre'
\psset{linecolor=black}
  \psbezier[linestyle=dotted](89357bp,342.83bp)(89368bp,340.2bp)(89510bp,307.69bp)(89521bp,305.16bp)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(1.2057e+05bp,1028bp)` must be in TeX notation, but the first one isn't.
However, the values make no real sense. You can scale the parts but it is not clear to me what you really want to show:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,2)(12,5)
\psset{xunit=0.0001,yunit=0.01}
  \psbezier[linejoin=2,showpoints]%
    (89357,342.83)(89368,340.2)(89510,307.69)(89521,305.16)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

you can also scale down the values but you'll also get an output without sense:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=50,yunit=5}
\begin{pspicture}(8.9,3)(9,4)
  \psbezier[linejoin=2,showpoints]%
    (8.9357,3.4283)(8.9368,3.402)(8.9510,3.0769)(8.9521,3.0516)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`1.2057e+05bp` means 1.2057*10^5bp, i.e. `120570bp` and that should be corrected manually. But it is about 40m! 89357bp (about 30 m) is also too big for TeX. Are you really expecting such dimensions? It seems to me that all `x`dimensions are 100 times too big.

Comment: Could it possible there is a bug in the dot2tex file? Should i manually change all occurrences of base e notation to decimal? If need be I can attach the original dot file and dot2tex generated file